# Formatting MMyyyy to MMyy

Tags: java, datetime, formatting

The following is my sample code:

```
String month = "09";

String year = "2014";

String monthYear = "092014";
```

The monthYear format is MMyyyy, I wish to format it to become MMyy. Thus, I am doing it as follows:

Method 1:

```
final SimpleDateFormat oriMonthYear = new SimpleDateFormat( "MMyyyy" );
final SimpleDateFormat changeMonthYear = new SimpleDateFormat( "MMyy" );

String newMonthYear = changeMonthYear.format( oriMonthYear.parse( month + year) );
```

This give me correct output, but I am not sure am I doing it by stupid way or not. I believe it should be another best practice and smart to way to do it.

Comment: That's pretty much it as far as using Java's libraries.  Though, that `month + year` is suspect...  You're better off using Joda.

Comment: [All information for datatime you have. ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `YearMonth` in Java 8 or later like below:

```java
YearMonth
        .parse(yearMonth, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(MMYYYY))
        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(MMYY));
```

Comment: `"MMyyyy"` or where do the constants arrive from?

Comment: Got my vote though: the new date time class is also usefull for working with YearMonths. And in modular java one need no SimpleDateFormat in ones application.

Answer (score 1):

Use Java's THreadLocal type to wrap your SimpleDateFormat objects.

```
ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> oriFormatHolder = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>() {

    @Override
    protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("MMyyyy");
    }
};


final SimpleDateFormat oriMonthYear = oriFormatHolder.get();
```

The reason for this is because SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe.

> Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

I actually ran into this problem.  In a multi threaded env we were sharing a SimpleDateFormat object across many threads and started getting bad results.  By wrapping it with ThreadLocal the problem went away.

Comment: An explanation *why* do this would be nice!

Comment: Rather, _do not_ use `ThreadLocal`. It's a wonderful way to shoot yourself in the knee if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @janos, I updated my answer with the reason why.

Answer (score 1):

If you are assured that the Strings you get form a valid date then you can just remove the first and second characters from the year string.

```
String newMonthYear = month + year.substring(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to change your date format in the future?

Do you always receive correct input?

Do you reformat dates in a performance-sensitive context?

If it is "No", "Yes" and "Yes" you're better off with `String.format` and `substring` to do what you want. Otherwise, `SimpleDataFormat` is the way to go ([don't forget synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#synchronization)).

The way you use `SimpleDataFormat` is perfectly correct (sans the string concatenation part), it's just more expensive resource-wise (to pay off for it being much more powerful tool).